# Does std::unordered_set take amortized constant lookup time for any object regardless of the predicate?

Tags: c++, c++11, hashset, unordered-set

In `std::unordered_set`, we provide a predicate to indicate whether two objects A and B are equal or not. My question is, suppose that we need `O(k)` time to determine if A and B are equal or not. Does the `unordered_set::find` still take amortized constant time or does it take amortized `O(k)` time?

Comment: O(k) on hit. It has to do at least one full comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The average constant lookup complexity guaranteed by `std::unordered_map` only refers to the number of elements in the map. If the map contains at least one element with the  same hash value *), it has to perform at least one full comparison of the key.  If that comparison is O(k), then obviously the lookup also becomes O(k), but that should only be relevant for pretty large k.

*) I guess in most implementations it is not just about the same Hash, but if there is an element in the same bucket.

Comment: It's not amortized constant, it's average case constant. The distinction is a bit subtle but important.